# Declaration of Arrays in Z3

Tags: z3

I am new to Z3. I am confused about what the following declaration of a one dimensional array in Z3 means

```
(declare-const a1 (Array t1 t2))
```

Is this a 1-D array of sort (type) *t1* or of sort (type) *t2*?

Is one of *t1* or *t2* the type of the indexing in array *a1*?

Could you suggest a reference to understand Z3? I have been following the tutorial on http://z3.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, t1 and t2 are index sort and element sort as defined by the [SMT theory for arrays](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories/ArraysEx.smt2).

The [Z3 Guide](http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial/guide) is probably the best place to start reading. It has a section on arrays too.